# Merging columns in several text files

Tags: unix, merge, edit, text-processing

I have several text files with this format

FILE1:

```
ID1 field1 field2
ID2 field1 field2
ID3 field1 field2
ID4 
ID5 field1 field2
ID6 field1 field2
```

FILE2:

```
    ID1 field3 field4
    ID2 field3 field4
    ID3 
    ID4 field3 field4
    ID5 field3 field4
    ID6 field3 field4
```

As you can see the fields may be missing in some of the rows.
What I want to do is merge all the text files together by the ID column under unix language.

My output should be like this:
OUTPUT FILE:

```
ID1 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 ... etc
ID2 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 ... etc
ID3 field1 field2 inserted string field5 ... etc
ID4 inserted string field3 field4 field5 ... etc
ID5 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 ... etc
ID6 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 ... etc
```

I have tried different commands but I usually ended up with a different number of rows. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
join file1 file12 -t $'inserted '
```

Comment: my IDs are actually phone numbers and some of them can be missing from other files

Comment: then replace null value with tabspace. using awk